# Call dbms_comparison Oracle package from function

Tags: database, oracle, comparison

I am posting this question as I am facing some errors when trying to use the dbms_comparison oracle package from an Oracle function.

I created a function which should return the scanID of the performed comparison to be able to retrieve the scanID's value from Java. However, the function is not being successfully executed as it is raising some errors. The dbms_comparison is being recognized as an identifier and therefore it is raising the following error: PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_COMPARISON' must be declared.

Please find below the Oracle function I created. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION compareRecords
    RETURN NUMBER IS
    scanID number;
    v_scan_info dbms_comparison.comparison_type;
    v_compare_result boolean;
    begin
         v_compare_result:= dbms_comparison.compare(
                         comparison_name => 'synchronised',
                         scan_info => v_scan_info,        
                         perform_row_dif => TRUE);

    dbms_output.put_line('Scan id: '||v_scan_info.scan_id);
    scanID := v_scan_info.scan_id;

    if v_compare_result = TRUE then
       dbms_output.put_line(a => 'Tables are synchronized!');
    else
       dbms_output.put_line(a => 'Warning! Data divergence found!'||chr(10));
    end if;
    RETURN scanID;
end compareRecords;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code as sys and was compiled successfully. As another user failed with

> PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_COMPARISON' must be declared.

So you have to add on your code `sys.` to `dbms_comparison` and need to `grant execute on sys.dbms_comparison to youruser`

Comment: I am trying to grant execute but it is giving insufficient privileges

Comment: @gla315 Are you connecting as sys?